# how to make a mysql query with 2 tables and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

i have this two tables:

**table 1:**

**employee:**

```
fname.  minit (example:John [B] Smith).    lname.   ssn.   bdate.     address.    sex.    salary.   dno.
```

**table 2:**

**department:**

```
dname.   dnumber.   mgrstartdate.   mgrssn.
```

foreign key is dnumber in department table and is connected with dno in employee table...

i want  query that will show me the`[lname,minit,fname,and adrress of the people that work in the department store]` as i said connection is dnumber from department table and dno from employee table `[dnumber has 1/4/5 as values and dno has 1/2/3/4/5 as values` so can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, perform a `JOIN` between the tables like

```
select e.lname,e.minit,e.fname,e.adrress
from employee e
join department d on e.dno = d.dnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT** employee.lname, employee.minit, employee.fname, employee.adrress 
**FROM** employee,department 
**WHERE** employee.dno = department.dnumber

or you can:

**SELECT** employee.lname, employee.minit, employee.fname, employee.adrress
**FROM** employee
**INNER JOIN** department **ON** employee.dno = department.dnumber